# MEAN app error: not able to get response from get request

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

**GET**

> Its making a get req but not returning any thing.Not even any error its just making get req again and again.

```
app.get('/:shortUrl',async (req,res)=>{
   try{ 
    const shortUrl = await shorturl.findOne({ short: req.params.shortUrl })
   .then(()=>{
      if(shortUrl == null) return res.sendStatus(404);
      res.redirect(shortUrl.full);
   })
  }
  catch{(error)=> console.log(error)};
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `await` as well as `.then` at the same time.

Either use **await** :

```
app.get('/:shortUrl',async (req,res)=>{
   try{ 
      const shortUrl = await shorturl.findOne({ short: req.params.shortUrl })
      if(!shortUrl) return res.sendStatus(404);
      res.redirect(shortUrl.full);
   } catch (error) {console.log(error)};
})
```

or use **.then**

```
app.get('/:shortUrl',(req,res)=>{
        shorturl.findOne({ short: req.params.shortUrl })
        .then(shortUrl => {
           if(!shortUrl) return res.sendStatus(404);
           res.redirect(shortUrl.full);
        })
        .catch(error => {console.log(error)};
    })
```